# How to print nicely?

Tags: python, printing

I have two classes:

```
class Dog(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
class Toy(object):
    def play(self):
        print "Squeak!"
```

I need to come up with a method called play(self, toy, n)  for class Dog. It prints "Yip! " (with a space) followed by the output from toy.play on the same line. This happens n times, with the n outputs on separate lines. If n is negative, it is the same as if it were 0.

What I did is

```
def play(self, toy, n):
    count = 1
    if n > 0:
        while count <= n:
            print "Yip! %s " % Toy().play()
            count += 1
    else:
        print None
```

However, when I call Dog('big').play(toy, 3) or whatever n is, it shows that
Squeak!
Yip! None 
Squeak!
Yip! None 
Squeak!
Yip! None 
I don't know what's wrong. Squeal! and Yip! should suppose to be at the same line while there are at separate now and there order should be opposite. And why there is a None?
Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example call, `Dog('big').play(0)`, you are **not** passing the `toy` argument -- that's what it's complaining about!  Pass a toy argument before `n` and that will be better.

Then you can start addressing the bugs in your `play` implementation: why are you making a new toy rather than use the argument, why are you printing `'None'` when that's not part of the specs, how you're uselessly printing the return value of the `Toy.play` method (which returns `None`, implicitly) rather than working along with the fact that the latter method is `print`ing something, and never incrementing `count` and so ending up in infinite loops.
(four serious bugs in eight lines plus one in the call just has to be some sort of a record, I believe;-).

BTW, homework is normally tagged with the tag `homework`, not `exercise`.  (And, there's a further bug in your Q's title, as no [classmethod](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=classmethod#classmethod) is actually around, just a good old plain and perfectly normal *instance* method).

Comment: Well, I'm sorry I made that many mistakes. But I sort of don't grab your idea. Could you please explain more explicitly how should I fix the play(). When I pass t = Toy(), then call Dog('big').play(t,3), it shows,
Squeak! separator line
Yip! None
Squeak! separator line
Yip! None
Squeak! separator line
Yip! None
However, I want to attain,
Yip! Squeak!/n
Yip! Squeak!/n
Yip! Squeak!.

Comment: @timy, so clearly you need to first print Yip without an end-of-line (a trailing comma on the `print` statement will do that of course), then just call `toy.play()` (which prints the rest of the line and the newline at the end).

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I see wrong is the you are attempting to call the class 'Toy' instead of the variable representing the instance 'toy' passed to you 'play' method. I don't believe you can instantiate a class and call one of its methods at the same time which is what 'Toy().play()' is trying to do. The other is that I'm not quite sure I understand what you are trying to do with the design of your classes. Here is how I would implement the classes and then use them to get your desired behavior.

```
class Toy(object):
    def play(self):
            return "Squeak!"

class Dog(object):
    speak = 'Yip! %s'

    def __init__(self, name, toy):
        self.name = name
        self.toy = toy

    def play(self,n):
        if n > 0:
            for each in range(n):
                print(self.speak % self.toy.play())
        else:
            print(None)
```

and here is how I would use it

```
Python 2.6.4 (r264:75821M, Oct 27 2009, 19:48:32)
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from toy import Toy, Dog
>>> spike = Dog("Spike",Toy())
>>> spike.play(3)
Yip! Squeak!
Yip! Squeak!
Yip! Squeak!
>>>
```

Comment: I'm so grateful for your solution. Well, the tricky is that this exercise require me to use one instance parameter for __init__ ,and two for play() method.  So can you think of how to fix play() by doing so? Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm didn't see the 'Homework' tag at first... my bad! The way I have it coded now is that Dog is a composite object. For you to have a Dog you must first have a Toy, which is not very realistic. But for the Dog to play, a Toy or some other amusement might be helpful. Look at what I've given you, and think about when the Toy should be given to the dog. Then think about how different variables are referenced and how the references should be changed depending on when the Toy is passed to the Dog object. Can you tell I use to tutor physics? Hint: You only need to alter four lines of code.